# Как пишутся комбинации покера?

Tags: кавычки, названия, строчная, заглавная

Тема по покерным комбинациям. Они должны писаться с кавычками или без? А буква строчная или заглавная?
К примеру: пара, две пары, сет, стрит, флеш, каре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Комбинации в покере**
https://academypoker.ru/combination.html

Пример:

***Стрит-флеш*** – это пять последовательных карт одной масти. Например, *стрит-флеш* до дамы. Если два или более игроков собирают стрит флеш, выигрывает тот, у кого старшая карта выше. Например, стрит-флеш до дамы (как в примере) бьет стрит-флеш до валета.

Названия комбинаций в покере – это **нарицательные** существительные, поэтому они пишутся **со строчной буквы.**

Кавычками (или курсивом) можно выделить эти видовые названия в сочетании с родовым словом, например: комбинация **«стрит-флеш».**